# Javascript: Object doesn't support this action error with onclick="status()"

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, status

I am getting an error in IE11 when attempting to call a function that is executing on click in a radio button.

Here is the html for the radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="filter" value="status" onclick="status()" checked>
```

The function is defined at the bottom of the page:

```
function status(){

    try{
        var td = document.getElementById("check1td");
        td.innerHTML = "Current (CURR)<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"skustat1\" value=\"CURR\" checked>";

        td = document.getElementById("check2td");
        td.innerHTML = "Test (TEST)<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"skustat2\" value=\"TEST\" checked>";

        td = document.getElementById("check3td");
        td.innerHTML = "Stocking Internet (SINET)<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"skustat3\" value=\"SINET\" checked>";

        td = document.getElementById("check4td");
        td.innerHTML = "Sellable Display (SLDSP)<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"skustat4\" value=\"SLDSP\" checked>";

    }
    catch(err){
        alert(err.message);     
    }
}
```

I have a similarly defined function on the sibling radio button and it is called correctly. So, my question is, is `status()` a reserved javascript function that IE won't respond to? And, if so, why does this work in other browsers?

EDIT: changed Status() to status() to reflect how it actually appears in my code.

UPDATE1: It also seems that it works when the browser is first opened in IE, maybe a caching issue?

Comment: Looks like it might just be a difference in capitalization.  JS is case-sensitive, and "Status" is different from "status".

Comment: Oh, wait, this works in other browsers?  Strike that.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi You need the `()` to make it call the function.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: YOU need the `()` don't listen to them :)

Comment: Sorry, i screwed up my question, status() is not capitalized on my radio button. exact error message is "Object doesn't support this action" in IE debugger.

Comment: yes. my bad. http://jsfiddle.net/hLmbk6bz/1/ you do need the `()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633183/different-javascript-object-literal-behaviour-in-firefox-google-chrome or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808614/javascript-variable-assignment-of-object-returns-string

Comment: @epascarello: Oh yes, the bad old days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use `status` as a variable in chrome (possibly other browsers too).

```
var internal = [];
for(var b in window) { 
  if(window.hasOwnProperty(b)) internal.push(b); 
}
console.log(internal); 

[... "status", ...]
```

Try renaming it to `Status()` or anything else. This code works: http://jsfiddle.net/hLmbk6bz/1

Comment: Is the code you posted part of the browser code? I'm not sure where you got it from.

Comment: No, the code is to show that `status` is a build in variable and youre not meant to mess with it. My point it just to rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener like this:

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener("click", status);
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bun4g2d0/4/

**HTML**

```
<input id="clickMe" type="radio" name="filter" value="status" onclick="status()" checked> 
    <div id="check1td"></div>
    <div id="check2td"></div>
    <div id="check3td"></div>
    <div id="check4td"></div>
```

**javascript**

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener("click", status);
        function status(){
    try{
        var td = document.getElementById("check1td");
        td.innerHTML = "Current (CURR)<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"skustat1\" value=\"CURR\" checked>";

        td = document.getElementById("check2td");
        td.innerHTML = "Test (TEST)<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"skustat2\" value=\"TEST\" checked>";

        td = document.getElementById("check3td");
        td.innerHTML = "Stocking Internet (SINET)<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"skustat3\" value=\"SINET\" checked>";

        td = document.getElementById("check4td");
        td.innerHTML = "Sellable Display (SLDSP)<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"skustat4\" value=\"SLDSP\" checked>";

    }
    catch(err){
        alert(err.message);     
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, and so does changing the name of the function. But why is the error occurring?

Comment: That might or might not solve the problem, but it doesn't explain why it's occuring.

Comment: With this solution you dont need the onclick="status()" at all since youre overriding it anyway.. why keep it? http://jsfiddle.net/bun4g2d0/5/

Comment: @JavierBuzzi out of laziness, who really cares if it is there or not, it's not doing anything lol.

Comment: The next guy man, thats why. I code by these words: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live."

Comment: That's up to you then lol, I work for myself, there is no next guy.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely the "status" name.  That's the only difference between this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/ux636prr

and this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/ux636prr/1/

But the second one, which changes "status" to "Status" works fine.

And an obligatory code link, although that Fiddle uses the same code as the question  :smile: :

```
<input type="radio" name="filter" value="status" onclick="status()" checked>
```

Comment: Ahh, yes, @epascarello's comments above explain it.  It's been a long time since I mucked about with `window.status`.... <shudder>

Answer (score 0):

My answer doesn't directly apply to this case, but I had the exact same error caused by a really similar and related problem. My function name was not a reserved word, but was the exact same name as my "name" attribute of my input radio.

```
<script>
function LoginType()
{
  // Code here never called because the function name is the same as my input name...
}
</script>
<input type="radio" name"LoginType" value="Windows" onclick="LoginType();" />
```

So I had to change my name like:

```
<input type="radio" name"radio_LoginType" value="Windows" onclick="LoginType();" />
```